# JSON conversion is getting failed

Tags: ios, swift3

Please review my code am badly stuck on this issue.

JSON conversion is not happening & it is going into catch block & printing following error.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

I've tried everything which is suggested here on StackOverflow but no luck.

I've trimmed my code for better understanding.

```
import Foundation


class Server
{

    class func convertStringToDictionary(_ data: Data) -> [String:Any]?
    {
        do
        {
            let convertedDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any]
            return convertedDict
        }

        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error)
        }

        return nil

    }

    class func registerUser( userInfo: String)
    {

        let url = URL(string: "http://132.148.18.11/missedprayers/welcome/register")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "request=" + userInfo
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        //----------------------------------------

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        {
            data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil
                else
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200
            {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            //--------------


            let finalData = Server.convertStringToDictionary(data)
            print(finalData)
        }

        task.resume()

    }


    func submitBtnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {


        let userInfoDict = [
            "name":"Maaz Patel",
            "phoneNum":"+91899885623",
            "email":"maaz@gmail.com",
            "city":"pune",
            "country":"India",
            "dobEnglish":"11-02-1992",
            "app":"Dalail",
            "aqeeda":"Sufi",
            "gender":"male",
            "MCCycle":""
        ]


        //-------------------

        do
        {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userInfoDict, options: [] )

            let jsonStr =  String.init(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

            Server.registerUser(userInfo: jsonStr!)

        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error)
        }
    }



}
```

Consider "SubmitBtnTapped" function is getting called from somewhere.

When am trying on Postman it's working also on Android same web service is working fine.
[image]

Comment: add `allowFragments` in your serlization `let convertedDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String:Any]`

Comment: Create a `String` from the returned `Data` and print it.

Comment: @vadian I've printed in String & it is showing print some PHP error but since it is working fine on Android & Postman. Am not able to blame PHP developer. I want to share what it is printing but I can not paste it here in the comment(It is reaching the limit). Can you please print it yourself.

Comment: Maybe you need to pass a header in the request to indicate that you are dealing with JSON.

Comment: @vaidan Tried but same issue persist.